# Express.js Router Downloading EJS File instead of Showing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

So, I'm in the process of creating a live video sharing/watching feature using Pure Node.js without the use of any frameworks.

However, while halfway through the development, I encountered an issue where Express is downloading an EJS file instead of rendering it.

How did I stumble upon this issue? Well, I'm building a Zoom room-like structure for my application, where a random string of digits is generated. This string is then sent to the server-side to create a private room, allowing users with the same ID to join. As a newcomer to Express.js, this is my first project utilizing it.

Below, you'll find snippets of my code from Room.ejs and the server-side.

```
So Here I am Linking My Modal(Which I Initially Used to Create and Join Room)

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#createPartyBtn').click(function () {
        $('#createJoinRoomModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#createRoomBtn').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '/create-room';
    });

    $('#joinRoomBtn').click(function () {
        window.location.href = '/join-room';
    });
});
```

```
My Home.js File
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#createPartyBtn').click(function() {
      $('#createJoinRoomModal').modal('show');
      $('#modalOverlay').show();
  });

  $('#createJoinRoomModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      $('#modalOverlay').hide();
  });

  function generateRoomID() {
      return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
  }

  $('#createRoomBtn').click(function() {
      var roomID = generateRoomID();
      window.location.href = '/room/' + roomID;
  });

  $('#joinRoomBtn').click(function() {
      var roomID = prompt('Enter Room ID:');
      if (roomID) {
          window.location.href = '/room/' + roomID;
      }
  });
});
```

```
My server.js File

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const path = require("path");
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/src"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/create-room", (req, res) => {
  const roomId = uuidv4(); // Generate a random room ID
  res.render("create-room", { roomId });
});


app.get("/join-room", (req, res) => {
  res.render("join-room");
});


app.post("/join", (req, res) => {
  const roomId = req.body.roomId;
  res.redirect(`/room/${roomId}`);
});

app.get("/room/:roomId", (req, res) => {
  const roomId = req.params.roomId;
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/src/room.ejs");
});
```

Also Following are my Files Directories

```
- Node_modules
- public (Contains CSS and JS files)
- src
   |- home.ejs
   |- room.ejs
   And other EJS files
- git
- yarn.lock
- package.json
- server.js
```

I Tried Renaming My File From Room.ejs to Room.html But IF i use room.html It wont let me use socket io. Always show some errors. Nor It help me to link external files.

Comment: `res.sendFile` is for downloading files.

Comment: _"using Pure Node.js without the use of any frameworks."_ Express.js is an external library. I don't see any files with an ejs extension in your directory tree. Never heard of ejs before your post.

Comment: EJS Stands For Embedded JavaScript. Its a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript. In Simple Words It Helps You Code JS While using HTML at the same time

Comment: So @Brahma Dev Should I use ```render()``` instead of ```sendFile()``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `server.js` file, you are sending the `"room.ejs"` file as a static file. This won't allow express to render it using the ejs view engine, this is why you are getting a download prompt when you hit the route. To fix it, instead of using `res.sendFile()`, use `res.render()` function as you did for the other routes. You can pass the `roomId` to the EJS file similar to how you passed it in `app.get("/create-room")`

> Example:

```
app.get("/room/:roomId", (req, res) => {
  const roomId = req.params.roomId;
  res.render("room", { roomId });
});
```